# How to use columns of a key in a dict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict as `dict = {'a': array[5, 5]}` , here `array[5, 5]` means it is read from a data file as a form of an array by 5X5. And I just want to use the first column of the value like `dict['a': array[:, 1]]`, how can I make it? Thanks!
Part of my code is:

```
coord['c%i' % i] = np.loadtxt('0cracknodecoord.txt', usecols=(0, 1))
print (coord['c1': array[:, [1]]])
```

The `print (coord['c1': array[:, [1]]])` didn't work.

Comment: @LenaBru I am using it on Win7 64 bit. Thx. The Python is 3.3.5. I also have numpy.

Comment: I mean, is it java, c, iphone, android, some other "Development" platform? Matlab? Which platform is it?

Comment: @LenaBru Sorry, I just use the python itself by installing it on my pc directly.

Comment: did you try array[:, [1]] ?

Comment: @LenaBru it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you want:

```
dict['a'][:,1]
```

You were pretty close already!

Comment: Quite strange, I tried that before but it didn't work. I thought I was wrong... T_T